# Microsoft Graph Api Webhook subscription via Rest Api not working anymore

Tags: azure, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, service-application

I have a working application that receive email webhook events from MS-Graph Api.
I noticed that I could not find the subscription back using the subscriptionId, I get a 404 error.I also cannot delete the subscription using the id.

I investigated further and noticed that I cannot create new subscriptions anymore:
The Application registered in Azure AD is a service-application (daemon)

My application auto renews the subscriptions and every time it did that I get a 202 response, but somehow the the subscription gets lost.

Request:

POST:  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions

`{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://myapi.azurewebsites.net/GraphWebhook/Inbox",
   "resource": "Users/myemail@company.nl/mailFolders('inbox')/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-10-25T20:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "subscription-identifier"
}`

Response:

```
"error": {
"code": "ExtensionError",
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "681ac550-be6f-4882-9b6b-e089c36ad38e",
  "date": "2016-10-25T10:13:25"
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: Working now again out of the blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API supports both user id and user email address as part of resource path and it **DOES NOT** change. To check whether it is API issue or resource issue, you could try to access your resource using [graph explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer):

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/myemail@company.nl/mailFolders('inbox')/messages

Regarding the error you saw when creating subscription, it looks like an Exchange issue related to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3006861).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to query all the subscriptions tied to a specific mailbox? I cannot find anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: No, it is not supported by the API at the moment. You can only query for a specific subscription using subscription id.

Comment: @CuongPham  I am getting the same error. I did not understand the solution. I have posted my issue here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample/issues/17. The error is in creating the subscription. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same error trying to subscribe to "created" notification on contacts folder. While "updated,deleted" works properly.